# Are there any implementations/examples of hierarchical classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, scikit-learn

Currently, I'm using `Scikit-learn` in `Python 3.6` to classify data with a 7-8 classes (e.g. `[C, A.1, A.2, B.3, B.1.1, B.1.2, B.2.1, B.2.2]` represented by dark borders below) but I started realizing that there is an inherent hierarchy in these groups that could be used during classification.  I was going to write my own algorithm but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if one exists.

**Does an algorithm that can predict class-labels in hierarchical manner like this exist (preferably in `Python`)?** If not, are there any examples of an approach like this being used?  It reminds me of layers in a neural network but I do not have nearly enough samples for a neural net.

For example, `A.1` and `A.2` in `Level-1` are subgroups of `Level-0_A`.  `Level-0_C` has no subgroups.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for digging an old post, but we just released a new library called HiClass (https://gitlab.com/dacs-hpi/hiclass) that tries to make it easy to create local hierarchical classifiers and I will be actively supporting it.

Comment: I’ll give yours a try. I made one as well.

Comment: @Fabio I am looking for such library that supports hierarchical classfication untl I landed here. Currently using `autoencoder` for feature extraction and then use the trained `encoder` sub-model to train a `random forest` for classification (multiclass, 5-classes). Is it possible to adopt this architecture in your library (base learning: `autoencoder`, meta-learner: `random forest`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't find an implementation of Hierarchical Classification on scikit-learn official documentation. But I found this repository recently. This module is based on scikit-learn's interfaces and conventions. I hope this will be useful.

https://github.com/globality-corp/sklearn-hierarchical-classification

It's possible to install it with pip:

```
pip install sklearn-hierarchical-classification
```

A thorough [usage example](https://github.com/globality-corp/sklearn-hierarchical-classification/blob/develop/examples/classify_digits.py) is provided in the repo .

Comment: Hi! If anyone was able to figure out how to use this package for deep hierarchy - please post a ling here if you could? For me it works for depth as in provided example, but I am not certain how to properly pass a deeper hierarchy

Comment: This link does not work anymore

Comment: I ended making my own package: https://github.com/jolespin/projects/blob/main/antimicrobial_resistance_modeling/Espinoza-Dupont_et_al_2021/Notebooks/markdown_version/Espinoza-Dupont_et_al_2021__Supplemental.md#v-architecture-and-construction-of-hec-graphical-models-for-moa-prediction but I need to split it out into a separate package once I finish my dissertation.

Comment: Can this package handle custom feature sets for each sub-model?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles across this, check out the package I developed to handle this type of data.

Here's the tutorial [investigating antibiotic resistance](https://github.com/jolespin/projects/blob/main/antimicrobial_resistance_modeling/Espinoza-Dupont_et_al_2021/Notebooks/markdown_version/Espinoza-Dupont_et_al_2021__Supplemental.md#v-architecture-and-construction-of-hec-graphical-models-for-moa-prediction)

The peer-reviewed publication is [Espinoza-Dupont et al. 2021](https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1008857)

Answer (score 0):

We just released a new library compatible with scikit-learn to create local hierarchical classifiers.

It can be easily installed with `pip install hiclass` or `conda install hiclass`. Documentation and examples can be found at https://gitlab.com/dacs-hpi/hiclass.

I hope this will be useful for future readers. :)

Comment: Can this package handle custom feature sets for each sub-model?

Comment: @O.rka, this is not supported at the moment. Out of curiosity, what would be an application for different feature sets in the local classifiers?

Comment: @Fabio I have some questions related to the package usage that I posted here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/609559/261548

Comment: @Fabio I did it here and it worked really well: https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1008857

Comment: @O.rka Thank you for the information! I will read through your paper and add this to the roadmap.